# Javascript clock color styling

Tags: javascript

I'm newbie to JS and would like to know if there's a way to modify the color of the "|" in between the clock hour and minutes in the code. I'd like it to be red.
Thanks for any help, hints and foremost explanations :)

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   "use strict";
   
   var textElem = document.getElementById("clock");
   var textNode = document.createTextNode("");
   textElem.appendChild(textNode);
   var curFontSize = 24;  // Do not changes
   
   function updateClock() {
    var d = new Date();
    var s = "";
    s += (10 > d.getHours  () ? "0" : "") + d.getHours() + "|";
    s += (10 > d.getMinutes() ? "0" : "") + d.getMinutes();
    textNode.data = s;
    setTimeout(updateClock, 60000 - d.getTime() % 60000 + 100);
   }
   
   
   function updateTextSize() {
    var targetWidth = 0.9;  // Proportion of full screen width
    for (var i = 0; 3 > i; i++) {  // Iterate for better better convergence
     var newFontSize = textElem.parentNode.offsetWidth * targetWidth / textElem.offsetWidth * curFontSize;
     textElem.style.fontSize = newFontSize.toFixed(3) * "pt";
     curFontSize = newFontSize;
    }
   }
   
   updateClock();
   updateTextSize();
   window.addEventListener("resize", updateTextSize);
  </script>
```

```css
 @font-face {
 font-family: Steelfish;
 src: url(Images/Steelfish.ttf);
}

    body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px black;
 font-family: Steelfish;
 font-weight:100;
 color:red;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#clock {
       position:absolute; top:-17px; left:205px; text-align:left; z-index:50;
       font-size:10pt;
    color:gray;
}

#minute{color:gray;}

#icon{position:absolute; top:24px; left:0px; width:50px; z-index:50;}

#location{
       position:absolute; top:50px; left:80px; width:250px; height:50px; text-align:left; z-index:50;
       color:#f79b00;
       font-size:17px;
}
#temperature{
       position:absolute; top:66px; left:160px; width:250px; height:50px; text-align:left; z-index:50;
       color:#248ffc;
       font-size:19px;
}
#condition{
       position:absolute; top:14px; left:80px; width:250px; height:50px; text-align:left z-index:50;
       color:f16000;
       font-size:19px;
}

#barre{
       position:fixed; top:62px; left:60px; width:140px; height:64px; text-align:left; z-index:12;
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="didLoadPage()">

<div id="barre"></div>

  <div id="wrap">
    <section id="topSection">
      <div id="left" style="width:40%;vertical-align:middle;">
        <p id="location"">London</p>
  <p id="clock" style="font-size:36pt;"></p>
        <p id="condition">Mostly Clear</p>
      </div>
      
      <div id="middle" style="width:20%;">
        <center>
          <img id="icon" src="IconSets/Sink/0.png" style="width:75px;" alt="" />
        </center>
      </div>
      
      <div id="right" style="width:40%;">
        <p><span id="temperature">10</span>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
                                 
                                 <script type="text/javascript">
   "use strict";
   
   var textElem = document.getElementById("clock");
   var textNode = document.createTextNode("");
   textElem.appendChild(textNode);
   var curFontSize = 24;  // Do not changes
   
   function updateClock() {
    var d = new Date();
    var s = "";
    s += (10 > d.getHours  () ? "0" : "") + d.getHours() + "|";
    s += (10 > d.getMinutes() ? "0" : "") + d.getMinutes();
    textNode.data = s;
    setTimeout(updateClock, 60000 - d.getTime() % 60000 + 100);
   }
   
   
   function updateTextSize() {
    var targetWidth = 0.9;  // Proportion of full screen width
    for (var i = 0; 3 > i; i++) {  // Iterate for better better convergence
     var newFontSize = textElem.parentNode.offsetWidth * targetWidth / textElem.offsetWidth * curFontSize;
     textElem.style.fontSize = newFontSize.toFixed(3) * "pt";
     curFontSize = newFontSize;
    }
   }
   
   updateClock();
   updateTextSize();
   window.addEventListener("resize", updateTextSize);
  </script>
                                            
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: replace "|" with "<span style=\"color:red;\">|</span>"

Comment: Thanks Ali for the help, but it doesn't seem to work... Unless I didn't understood right... If I change the "|' as you said in the script, it's ends up like this: http://imgur.com/4h3BNFL

Comment: Please check my answer below. You will see an updated JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/fhv6r0sL/

You might want to add an inline element to wrap around the `|`

Since you created a textNode you won't be able to add any HTML tag right away.

Here's the updated JS code.

```
"use strict";

            var textElem = document.getElementById("clock");
            // var textNode = document.createTextNode("");
            // textElem.appendChild(textNode);
            var curFontSize = 24;  // Do not changes

            function updateClock() {
                var d = new Date();
                var s = "";
                s += (10 > d.getHours  () ? "0" : "") + d.getHours() + "<span class='timePipe'>|</span>";
                s += (10 > d.getMinutes() ? "0" : "") + d.getMinutes();
                textElem.innerHTML = s;
                setTimeout(updateClock, 60000 - d.getTime() % 60000 + 100);
            }


            function updateTextSize() {
                var targetWidth = 0.9;  // Proportion of full screen width
                for (var i = 0; 3 > i; i++) {  // Iterate for better better convergence
                    var newFontSize = textElem.parentNode.offsetWidth * targetWidth / textElem.offsetWidth * curFontSize;
                    textElem.style.fontSize = newFontSize.toFixed(3) * "pt";
                    curFontSize = newFontSize;
                }
            }

            updateClock();
            updateTextSize();
            window.addEventListener("resize", updateTextSize);
```

Here I've removed the part where you created a textNode and attached that to the `textElem` div.

After that instead of `|` it's now `"<span class='timePipe'>|</span>"`, so that we can style the `timePipe` class.

CSS

```
.timePipe {
color: red;
}
```

Now we can inject the `var s` as an HTML to the `textElem` using the innerHTML method.

`textElem.innerHTML = s`

Note that it's fine even if you create a textNode, but we need HTML to style the `|`. So there's no point of having one there, rather add the content as HTML.

Hope that helps